# Connected component not getting props on initial render. mapStateToProps not being called?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

This is the parent component. There would be several lines here selectively rendering connected components

```
//Parent Component
getInitialState(){
    return {
        active_component: 'UserList'
    };
},
render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    {this.state.active_component === 'UserList'?<UserList />:null}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

This is the connected component

```
//UserList component that fails to load props

let UserList = React.createClass({
    render(){
        let users = this.props.user_list.map((user,idx)=>{
            return <UserListItem user={user} idx={idx} />
        });
        return(
            <div>
                <div>
                    Users
                </div>
                <div style={{display:this.props.fetching_users?'flex':'none'}}>
                    fetching users ...
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        {users}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        user_list: state.admin.user_list,
        fetching_users: state.admin.fetching_users
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserList);
```

The .map() on the user_list prop fails because there are no props. The component works fine on its own outside the ternary. There's something I'm missing I'm just not sure what. 
Any insight or alternative methods to accomplish what I'm going for would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does your action/reducer look like that populates `user_list`? If you're fetching the list asynchronously, it could not exist on render which would throw the exception when calling `.map()`.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you run

Comment: the reducer in this instance is already populated. i have already ruled out the possibility of user_list being undefined or empty.